# How to add cross validation in logistic regression from scratch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, cross-validation

I am new to python and machine learning. I've coded logistic regression from scratch and I want to add cross validation. Could I somehow split the training data into 5 divisions after doing train test split, then run my algorithm on each section of that split? Trying to add sklearn's cross validation hasn't been working for me with this from scratch. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

def Sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1 + np.exp(-z))

def Hypothesis(theta, X):   
    return Sigmoid(X @ theta)

def Cost_Function(X,Y,theta,m):
    hi = Hypothesis(theta, X)
    _y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)
    J = 1/float(m) * np.sum(-_y * np.log(hi) - (1-_y) * np.log(1-hi))
    return J

def Cost_Function_Derivative(X,Y,theta,m,alpha):
    hi = Hypothesis(theta,X)
    _y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)
    J = alpha/float(m) * X.T @ (hi - _y)
    return J

def Gradient_Descent(X,Y,theta,m,alpha):
    new_theta = theta - Cost_Function_Derivative(X,Y,theta,m,alpha)
    return new_theta

def Accuracy(theta):
    correct = 0
    length = len(X_test)
    prediction = (Hypothesis(theta, X_test) > 0.5) 
    _y = Y_test.reshape(-1, 1)
    correct = prediction == _y
    my_accuracy = (np.sum(correct) / length)*100
    print ('LR Accuracy: ', my_accuracy, "%")

def Logistic_Regression(X,Y,alpha,theta,num_iters):
    m = len(Y)
    for x in range(num_iters):
        new_theta = Gradient_Descent(X,Y,theta,m,alpha)
        theta = new_theta
        if x % 100 == 0:
            print #('theta: ', theta)    
            print #('cost: ', Cost_Function(X,Y,theta,m))
    Accuracy(theta)
ep = .012 
initial_theta = np.random.rand(X_train.shape[1],1) * 2 * ep - ep
alpha = 0.5
iterations = 10000
Logistic_Regression(X_train,Y_train,alpha,initial_theta,iterations)
```

Comment: Why cross validation from sklean is not working for you? What error did you get?

Comment: I was trying cross_val_score, putting it in this code at the end with: scores = cross_val_score((Logistic_Regression(X_train,Y_train,alpha,initial_theta,iterations)), X_train, Y_train, cv=5)
print(scores). Gave the error: 
TypeError: estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit' method, None was passed

Comment: I see. For sklean's cross_val_score, you need to pass in a model object with `fit` method implemented, which you don't have for your `Logistic_Regression`. I think what you can do is to implement cross validation by yourself. Initial idea is to shuffle your data, and then segment your data by index depending on the cv number (`n_cv`) you want, and then fit using `n_cv-1` and predict on the remaining.